# DISTINCT or GROUP BY used with NOT IN returns wrong results

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7

I have two tables
users with columns: uid, name, mail, etc
users_roles with columns: uid, rid

In users_roles, each time a role is added to a user, it is listed in the users_roles table. So, let's say user 1 has roles 1 and 4. In the table:

```
users_roles:  
uid | rid  
 1  |  1  
 1  |  4
```

I need to return all users who don't have roles 4 OR 5. I have tried using both Group By and Distinct combined with NOT IN. The problem I keep running into is if a user has both roles 1 and 4, they will be returned in the results. Below is a an example of my Group By query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN users_roles AS ur ON u.uid = ur.uid
WHERE ur.rid NOT
IN ( 4, 5 )
GROUP BY ur.uid
```

I have tried sub-queries as well to no avail because the issue seems to be that Group By combines rows after finishing the query. So, it simply finds the record containing uid 1 rid 4 and returns it in the results.

The Drupal module Views that I can't use (due to security issues with Views Bulk Operations) accomplishes the desired results by doing the following:

```
LEFT JOIN users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid 
AND (users_roles.rid = '4' OR users_roles.rid = '5')
```

For long term maintenance I don't want to have to update the code every single time we add a role and this is going to make for one long query.

I looked at the following:
[Aggregating Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4768499)
[Filtering distinct rows in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796468/filtering-distinct-rows-in-sql)

While there are Drupal functions that will let me get the list of role ids where I could unset the roles I don't want show up in the resulting array, I feel like I am missing a fundamental understanding of SQL. Is there a better way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to return all users who don't have roles 4 & 5

```
select  *
from    users u
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    users_roles ur
        where   ur.rid in (4,5)
                and ur.uid = u.uid
        )
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm! I wasn't entirely clear when I said 4 & 5, I meant or and this works great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for no existance of both 4 and 5 (and not neccessarily one of them), you can use

```
select  * 
from    users u 
where   not exists 
        ( 
        select  uid
        from    users_roles ur 
        where   ur.rid in (4,5)     
                and ur.uid = u.uid 
    group by uid having count(distinct rid)=2
        )
```

If the list is long you can use a mapping table with all possible values and use that in the above query

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my question. I meant to say 4 or 5 but this does work as advertised! In fact, the more I play with it the more I realize how much fine grained control you can get with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would like that :

```
SELECT *
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN users_roles AS ur ON (u.uid = ur.uid AND ur.rid IN ( 4, 5 ) )
WHERE ur.rid IS NULL
GROUP BY u.uid
```

Comment: A quick test shows that this seems to work. I'll really have to dig down later tomorrow to figure out if it returns different results from the first answer. Is this a short hand notation for NOT EXISTS?

Comment: It's not a short hand for NOT EXISTS. This solution avoids going through a subquery. Can you test the speed between the two solutions? I think my solution is more faster.

Comment: Right now, I have such a small dataset (~50 records) that the two solutions are neck in neck every single time I run a query. When I have a larger dataset (or the time to create a fake one) I'll get back to you on that.